# Generating an IPython script in a zc.buildout

Tags: python, ipython, buildout

I use IPython all the time here on my machine instead of the default Python interpreter because it has a lot more features and generally feels more powerful. I'd like to use it in my zc.buildout project as an intepreter in the `bin` directory like the generated Python interpreter generated created by this section in `buildout.cfg`:

```
[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

This generates a script in `bin/python` which is a Python interpreter with access to all of my project dependencies.

I wanted to do the same with IPython and with a quick Google gave me the following Buildout recipe:

```
[ipython]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ipython
script = ipython
```

However, this doesn't generate an IPython interpreter in `bin`, it seems to not really do anything.

How can I generate a IPython interpreter for my buildout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
[ipython_part]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
       ipython
scripts = ipython
```

Don't forget to add the part to buildout:

```
[buildout]
parts = something something_else ipython_part
```

Other scripts available in IPython 0.13: iplogger, iptest, ipcluster, pycolor, ipcontroller, irunner, ipengine.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have just the 'ipython_part' in my parts list. No scripts are generated. What version of buildout are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by Justas should work, except in these cases, when ipython is already installed system-wide.

To workaround this, run buildout inside virtualenv. Virtualenv must be created with --no-site-packages:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages env
env/bin/python bootstrap.py
bin/buildout
```

Comment: The option --no-site-packages is set by default and so it is obsolete in recent versions of virtualenv (at least since version 1.9).